# Reading more than 4096 bytes per chunk with part.Read

Tags: go

I'm trying to process a multipart file upload in small chunks to avoid storing the entire file in memory. The following function seems to solve this, however when passing a `[]byte` as the destination for the `part.Read()` method, it reads the part in chunks of 4096 bytes instead of in chunks of the destination size (`len([]byte)`).

When opening a local file and `Read()`'ing it into a `[]byte` of the same size, it uses the entire space available as expected. Thus I think it's something specific to the `part.Reader()`. However, I'm unable to find anything about a default or max size for that function.

For reference, the function is as follows:

```
func ReceiveFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  reader, err := r.MultipartReader()
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  if reader == nil {
    panic("Wrong media type")
  }
  buf := make([]byte, 16384)
  fmt.Println(len(buf))
  for {
    part, err := reader.NextPart()
    if err == io.EOF {
      break
    }
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    var n int
    for {
      n, err = part.Read(buf)
      if err == io.EOF {
        break
      }
      if err != nil {
        panic(err)
      }
      fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes into buf\n", n)
      fmt.Println(len(buf))
    }
    n, err = part.Read(buf)
    fmt.Printf("Finally read %d bytes into buf\n", n)
    fmt.Println(len(buf))
  }
```

Comment: An [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) isn't guaranteed to read any specific amount. That's why it returns the number of bytes read. You're also checking for `io.EOF` before checking `n`, which means you could lose data here. Read that linked documentation carefully.

Comment: Ah, I must have missed that part. I guess not mentioning anything about guaranteed amount of bytes read is the same as not guaranteeing it...

Thanks for pointing the part of checking `io.EOF` out before checking `n` - I'll make sure to do that in production (Code snippet is simply a small testcase I wrote, quickly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part reader does not attempt to fill the caller's buffer as allowed by the [io.Reader](http://godoc.org/io#Reader) contract.

The best way to handle this depends on the requirements of the application.

If you want to slurp the part into memory, then use [ioutil.ReadAll](https://godoc.org/io/ioutil#ReadAll):

```
for {
    part, err := reader.NextPart()
    if err == io.EOF {
      break
    }
    if err != nil {
      // handle error
    }
    p, err := ioutil.ReadAll(part)
    if err != nil {
      // handle error
    }
    // p is []byte with the contents of the part
}
```

If you want to copy the part to the io.Writer `w`, then use [io.Copy](https://godoc.org/io#Copy):

```
for {
    part, err := reader.NextPart()
    if err == io.EOF {
      break
    }
    if err != nil {
      // handle error
    }
    w := // open a writer
    _, err := io.Copy(w, part)
    if err != nil {
      // handle error
    }
}
```

If you want to process fixed size chunks, then use [io.ReadFull](https://godoc.org/io#ReadFull):

```
 buf := make([]byte, chunkSize)
 for {
    part, err := reader.NextPart()
    if err == io.EOF {
      break
    }
    if err != nil {
      // handle error
    }
    _, err := io.ReadFull(part, buf)
    if err != nil {
      // handle error
      // Note that ReadFull returns an error if it cannot fill buf
    }
    // process the next chunk in buf
}
```

If the application data is structured in some other way than fix sized chunks, then [bufio.Scanner](https://godoc.org/bufio#Scanner) might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead change the chunk size, why not use `io.ReadFull` ?

https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull

This can manage the entire logic, and if can't read it will just return an error.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seems that `io.ReadFull` would solve my problem if I replaced `n, err = part.Read(buf)` with `n, err = io.ReadFull(part, buf)` - However, I'm not aware wether or not `io.ReadFull` will, when wrapped in a for loop, read all the data in chunks of size X, or read the same chunk of size X over and over again?

Comment: @MadsRC you can't "read the same chunk over and over again" without seeking (and even then, only if a stream is seekable, which a `multpart.Part` is not). Reading data always moves the read point forward.